# jQuery UI selectmenu - how to append option to optgroup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, select-menu

I've figured out how to append options to a select box dynamically - but the additions are appended to the end and not included in an optgroup.

How can I accomplish that? Here is the code that currently just appends to the selectmenu:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    roles = $("#roles").selectmenu();
    roles.append("<option value='"+'test!'+"'>" + 'test!' + "</option>");
    roles.selectmenu();
    // let's say I wanted to append to the optgroup labeled 'Your roles' instead. How?
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="role-select" style="margin-left:30px; margin-top:-10px; float:left;">
      <form action="#">
        <fieldset>
          <label for="roles">Select a role to edit</label>
          <select name="roles" id="roles">
            <optgroup label="Your roles">
              <option value="empty">random 1</option>
              <option value="noreason">2</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Default roles">
              <option value="vvv">3</option>
              <option value="somsdfsdfile">4</option>
            </optgroup>
          </select>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to select the opgroup you want to append it to. For example:

```
var roles = $("#roles");
roles.find('optgroup[label="Your roles"]').append("<option value='"+'test!'+"'>" + 'test!' + "</option>");
```

Comment: I encountered a very weird error using this solution. Appending the option seems to be working (apparently), but around 50 % of the time I get an error when clicking the selectmenu after appending an option to it. [error message](http://imgur.com/6854BII)

Comment: And on some occations the option is being appended without any error, but the option is not visible in the selectmenu.

Comment: You may wanna call `roles.selectmenu('refresh');` at the bottom of the `addRole` function

Edit: it re-renders the menu and processes the added items http://api.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#method-refresh